# Is there a way to print migration file when I run a generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails is convenient in that it lets you run generators to create migration files, models, views, controllers, etc.

However everytime I generate a migration using--for example, `rails generate migration add_title_to_posts title:string`, I open up the resulting migration file to see that the result is same as I expected. It's kind of annoying because i have to do this every time.

I was wondering if there's an easy way to print the resulting migration file when I run the generator.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

the generate command doesn't have an option like what you're looking for, but you can always do a cat command(on linux), OSX should have cat too or something similar, at least then you can see the file after execute the command on the terminal or if you really, really, really want to have that, do a sh bash that execute booth commands with the parameters that you execute... i just know i wouldn't.

```
cat db/migrate/20140515041846_add_default_to_sliders.rb
```

PS:

```
rails g
```

execute rails g for see all the options for generate